# What are Best Practice for msgprop.EnumProperty and messages.Enum with Python 3 and Cloud NDB?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

With Python 2 and NDB, we could store Enum in entities' properties this way:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import msgprop
from protorpc import messages

class CoreWebhookService(messages.Enum):
    UNKNOWN = 0
    AUTH0 = 1

class CoreWebhook(ndb.model):
    service = msgprop.EnumProperty(CoreWebhookService, required=True)
    url = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

With Python 3, based on [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/migrate-to-cloud-ndb#models), it says `If you try to create these objects, a NotImplementedError will be raised.` for google.appengine.ext.ndb.msgprop.EnumProperty.

I understand

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

is getting replaced by

```
from google.cloud import ndb
```

but **what's the best practice for Enum from now on since it not implemented?**

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I don't have a test project to verify this, but python 3 has enums.  You should be able to do something straight forward like:

```
from enum import IntEnum

class CoreWebhookService(IntEnum):
    UNKNOWN = 0
    AUTH0 = 1

class CoreWebhook(ndb.model):
  service = IntegerProperty(required = true, choices=list(CoreWebhookService))
  url = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Comment: Thx for the response. I will give it a try. The IntegerProperty makes total sense. I was not sure it is the official way to deal with this though. I guess it will be from now on... thx @jim-morrison